# Can I customize the icon Finder uses for PDF/Preview files?

Tags: finder, preview, icon

How can I disable the "dog ears" my PDF previews have in Finder?

This is most easily seen in windows with icon view. (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> is the shortcut). Is it possible to customize this icon so it is similar, but with the corner  not folded over like a page that has been dog-eared?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the dog-ears, as that is how the Finder renders the images. Most OS X apps' document icons have that dog-ear on the icon image so it looks more like a physical page and less like an unadorned white square.